# php regex to dissect a literal regex to determine whats being looked for

Tags: php, regex, validation

This is going to need a better mind than mine...how to extract the pattern a literal regex is looking for.

My app interfaces with an API that is providing Validation Regex's for particular strings regarding user input on specific fields.  An example of this would be for Country Postal codes:

```
Canada, {"ValidationRegex" : "^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z][\\s\\-]?\\d[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]\\d$" }
United Kingdom, {"ValidationRegex": "((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([AZa-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})|GIR0AA" }
```

I am trying to analyze the Regex pattern to see if its letters only, numbers only or mixed.  Then based on the validation formats being tested for various strings, I want to force display the type of keyboard displayed to the user for that particular input field.  Keyboard types are based on `TEXT, TEL, NUMBER` as well as put `<input>` length or range restrictions based on the validation requirements. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any other info provided that would allow me to accurately determine keyboard type or string lengths or than trying to break down the Validation Regex.

This is for potentially hundreds of different types of validation regexs so I am hoping to find a universal way of extracting the necessary info from each of the Validation Regex expressions to determine if the string code is number only or requires characters...and length ranges.

Comment: So to be absolutely clear: The text that is being assessed is the regex rule itself, and you want to find out if it is(amongst other options) numeric only, and it's length. First judgement seems that there are so many iterations possible....

Comment: @Martin - you are correct.  Regex'ing a regex expression.  I have come up with a method that can accurately get about 85% of what is being sent over the api but unfortantely there is a good 15+% that I can't use alternative methods on and the only way to get the data is by anlayzing the regexp

Answer (score 0):

While you can sort of automate this by making your own regex rules, there is too much of a margin for error for it to be something worth relying on. An approach to consider would be to dump all of their validation strings into a SQL table.  Then you can sort them all in a way that each unique regex pattern is assigned an ID.  Then in a second table you can match each of those IDs to a class TEXT, TEL, NUMBER, etc.

So You'd have tables that look like this:

```
tblRegexStrings
id | uniqueID | location         | regex
1    1          'Canada'           "^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z][\\s\\-]?\\d[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]\\d$"
2    2          'United Kingdom'   "((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([AZa-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})|GIR0AA"
3    2          'France'           "((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([AZa-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})|GIR0AA"

tblRegexClasses
uniqueID | classType
1          'TEXT'
2          'TEL'
```

If there is a significant amount of reuse in regex patterns (which I suspect there will be), then this will help reduce it to a reasonable number of classes that you can assign by hand.  So, if 50 locations use the same regex pattern as the United Kingdom, you can set all of thier classes at once by changing the classType of line 2 in tblRegexClasses.

If it is still so much data that you need to regex it, but there is also a lot of reuse, then I'd still recommend using this since you will still need to traige your data. Since your regex functions may make bad assumptions, or so you don't need to make tons of exceptions for every fringe case.